# Qt Cannot access *ui pointer from inheriting class

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, inheritance, objective-c++

I am trying to write an application where I would have a generic dialog window and specific dialog windows that would inherit some basic functionalities from the generic one. I am not sure this is the best approach for this, but this is how I did it (The CGenericProject class was created from Dialog template in Qt Creator):

CGenericProject.h:

```
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class CGenericProject;
}

class CGenericProject : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CGenericProject(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CGenericProject();

protected:
    Ui::CGenericProject *ui;
};
```

CGenericProject.cpp:

```
#include "cgenericproject.h"
#include "ui_cgenericproject.h"

CGenericProject::CGenericProject(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CGenericProject)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

CGenericProject::~CGenericProject()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

CEisProject.h:

```
#include "cgenericproject.h"

class CEisProject : public CGenericProject
{
public:
    CEisProject();
    ~CEisProject();

};
```

CEisProject.cpp:

```
#include "ceisproject.h"

CEisProject::CEisProject()
{
    ui-> NO ACCESS
}

CEisProject::~CEisProject()
{

}
```

As you see in the `CEisProject.cpp` file, I have no access to the `ui` field inherited from `CGenericProject`, even though it is `protected`. I mean, I see `ui` itself, but I dont see its methods and members. Any other variable that I would define there, would be accessible. What's wrong? I would appreciate all help in this manner.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your code without trying to access ui? Does it give you any error?

Comment: The code compiles perfectly well, I have also run qmake again.

Comment: Since you create a new Ui::CGenericProject in the constructor of Ui::CGenericProject, I'd expect your program to keep creating new instances "forever".

Comment: But I run the constructor only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the line

```
#include "ui_cgenericproject.h"
```

to the `CEisProject.cpp` file.

The `CGenericProject.h` file is included in `CEisProject.h`, but `CEisProject.h` does not have access to `CGenericProject.cpp`. In the header of your base class you have a only forward declaration of `Ui::CGenericProject`, and you include its file in the .cpp. So `CGenericProject.cpp` knows the implementation of this class.

But `CEisProject.cpp` doesn't have access to that, so you have to include the file again in here.

**NOTE**
Your forward declaration is confusing, you should indent it properly. Also, add some comments to your code to add some clarity for who is reading it, you're using two different classes with the same name.

Comment: Indeed this was the case. But in this case, isnt it better to move `#include "ui_cgenericproject.h"` to the `CGenericProject.h` instead?

Comment: Yes, but that depends on what you do in `ui_cgenericproject.h`. You should do what you're doing right now to avoid circular dependencies, but if you never use these classes in `ui_cgenericproject.h` (or any header file included there) you can do that.